# Simple Python trading system example: Populating a pandas dataframe and exporting to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

This is a simple trading system in Python that dumps the results to an excel spreadsheet. I first populate the final dataframe 'trades' (excel column 'trades') with an 'x' whenever the criteria is met. I need to replace the rest of the 'x's with the buy price for each trade. So far the code puts the buy price on the top only. Here's the code using yfinance to get the stock data:
'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import xlsxwriter as xl
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

stock="SPY"
filename=stock+'.xlsx'
yf.pdr_override()
startyear=2000
startmonth=1
startday=1
start=dt.datetime(startyear, startmonth, startday)
now=dt.datetime.now()
df=pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock,start,now)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

df = pd.read_excel (filename)
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
df['5 sma']=df['Close'].rolling(window=5).mean().round(5)
df['criteria']=df['Close']<=df['5 sma']
df['criteria']=df['criteria'].astype(int)
df.loc[df['criteria'] ==1,'trades']='x'
df.loc[df['criteria'] > df['criteria'].shift(1),'trades']=df['Adj Close']
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

'''

Comment: Please provide sample input. I ran your code against a test excel file and it worked correctly.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the code to get the data using yfinance and saves to an excel file.

Comment: Thank you. That helps clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like ffill is the missing piece. Try this code

```
df = pd.read_excel (filename)
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
df['5 sma'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=5).mean().round(5)
df['criteria'] = df['Close'] <= df['5 sma']
df['criteria'] = df['criteria'].astype(int)
df['trades'] = '' # new column, default value
df.loc[df['criteria'] > df['criteria'].shift(1),'trades']=df['Adj Close'] # first 1 only
df.loc[(df['criteria'] == 1) & (df['trades'] == ''),'trades'] = np.NaN # for repeats
df['trades'] = df['trades'].fillna(method = 'ffill') # fill NaN with previous non-NaN value
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code replaces the 'x's with the Adj Close each day.  What I need is the Adj Close for the first day of the trade to replace all the 'x's.  In other words, one number replacing the 'x's. Also, I realize I don't need the 'x's, but kept them in to help explain what I need.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much Mike.